# How to add our own defined tab in the doxygen docs

Tags: tabs, doxygen, page-title, doxygen-wizard, doxygen-addtogroup

[Output of your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NG9N5.png)[image]

[image: FPGA_BOARD content]

Hi I want to add one more tab to the page i.e I want "Lokesh" tab in between Main Pages and Related pages
I have attached screenshot for reference.
[image: Image for the reference]

[image]

[image: Detailed tab view]

Comment: Which version of doxygen? What did you try so far? Did you have a look at the paragraph "Changing the layout of pages" (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) in the documentation?

Comment: Thanks albert fro your help yes I am able to do it.

Comment: One more issue is there if I want to add modules and submodules inside our own user group how I will do it. It will be very greatful if you look into this

Comment: By head the "usergroup" can be nested (see documentation), when there are still problems come back with an example of what you tried.

Comment: Hi albert  thanks for your quick response, I have tried defgroup but it is not working if I am using defgroup modules has been created in modules tag not in the user tag. Could you please explain "By head the" in your comment.

Comment: I wasn't talking about `\defgroup` but about the "usergroups" in the DoxygenLayout.xml as described ink I provided before.

Comment: Link is not visible

Comment: Strange do you get an error message or something similar? With your distribution you will have also have the documentation or you should be able to download it from the same place as where you got doxygen. Which OS are you using and which doxygen version?

Comment: Hi Albert inside FPGA_BOARD tag I want  "https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSeq5.png" this type of menu. I have attached image above.

Comment: Code should always be added as code to a question and not as an image, to reproduce is is much harder to use and image than code. There should not only be images added to the question but also some accompanying text to show what it is. From your tests what are the results, wheer are the problems?

Comment: Hi albert As per the image requirement is clear to you or not if not give me your email id I will send whole module to you for rectification.Inside FPGA_BOARD tab I want modules which is shown in image.

Comment: What is of interest is only the changes you made to the DoxygenLayout.xml, the result in the user interface and a description what is missing / wrong.

Comment: In the user interface i.e (FPGA_BOARD tab)  I want Modem,Modem Api,Threadx etc  as Its shown in the image which is updated earlier.Currently Inside FPGA_BOARD tag I am getting FPGA top view and modem but it is not coming as group. So please suggest how to create our own group inside FPGA_BOARD tab just same as modules tab. but content of the modules tab and FPGA_BOARD tag must be different for my specific requirement.I have attached screenshot for reference.

Comment: It is unclear which image belongs to which remark. Please add these type of descriptions to the question and do not dump the images in the question and a description in the comments, make a "logical" story out of it. Also give your new entries in the DoxygenLayout.xml. Now it is unclear.

Comment: In simple tell me one thing how I will define subgroup inside our <tabtype ="usergroup" title ="FPGA_BOARD">

Comment: Still very unclear what you want.

Comment: The code which you posted I tried that one but it is showing the output which I have attached in latest image. But my requirement is like I want to create group inside "Think" tab using @defgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but hard to put in a comment.

The question is still very unclear but maybe the user wants something like:

```
    <tab type="usergroup" visible="yes" title="Think" intro="">
      <tab type="usergroup" visible="yes" title="ReThink" intro="">
        <tab type="user" visible="yes" title="Think Longer" intro="">
        </tab>
      </tab>
    </tab>
```

in his `DoxygenLayout.xml`.